# Cannot set specific column widths in bootstrap gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview, boundfield

I have a gridview:

```
     <asp:GridView ID="ParentSelect" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="ParentSelect_RowCommand" OnRowCreated="ParentSelect_RowCreated" emptydatatext="Please Submit A Clip. C'mon dude." ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="600" CssClass= "table table-striped table-bordered table-condense" OnDataBound="ParentSelect_DataBound" DataKeyNames="SubmissionID" RowStyle-Wrap="true">
    <HeaderStyle BorderColor="Black" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField ="SubmissionID" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Vote" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-CssClass="DisplayCenterHeaderGrid">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Imagebutton ID="VoteUp" runat="server" ImageUrl="Content/glyphicons-202-upload.png" Width="20" ToolTip="Vote Up" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>
        " CommandName="VoteUp" OnCommand="VoteUp_Command" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField ="Title" HeaderText="Title" Visible="True" HeaderStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="DisplayCenterHeaderGrid"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField ="VideoUrl" HeaderText="Title" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField ="Description" HeaderText="Title" Visible="false" />             
        <asp:BoundField DataField ="GenreSelection" HeaderText="Genre" Visible="True" HeaderStyle-Width="30" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-CssClass="DisplayCenterHeaderGrid" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have tried virtually every way imaginable to set specific column widths and have been unsuccessful in doing so. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `ItemStyle-Width` this property for your `BoundField`

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField ="Title" HeaderText="Title" Visible="True" 
  HeaderStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="DisplayCenterHeaderGrid"
  ItemStyle-Width="300px"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by bootstrap grid ? then try with `30%`

Comment: It's a gridview that has a bootstrap style over it. Using the bootstrap framework.

Comment: then you can override those styles using your custom css

Comment: My custom CSS is this: 
.DisplayCenterHeaderGrid
{
width:30% 
}

and it didn't work. Any Ideas? and thanks for your help.

Comment: need to investigate more which is the actual style get applied while rendering the page... Your styles may be override by the derived styles from bootstrap...

Answer (score 0):

In design view, click the GridView handle. Convert the BoundField to a TemplateField.  Edit the template. Set the width property of the control in the ItemTemplate.

resulting sample code:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="comments">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("comments") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("comments") %>' Width="400px"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```